# In servlet / filter, How to get the urls list which are not configured with auth-constraint

Tags: java, tomcat, basic-authentication, servlet-filters

Have two **security-constraint** in web.xml. Only one **security-constraint** has **auth-constraint** in it.
So now, I need to do some operation specifically to the urls that are configured under the **security-constraint** which doesn't has the **auth-constraint** .
Is there any way to find these url patterns in servlet / filter ?